# How can I get the total number of comparisons after the 100 loops have finished?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, unique

The program runs 100 times and prints out the unique elements out of 140 integers.

Since it needs to compare two integers to tell if they are unique or not, how can I print out the total number of comparisons?

Here is my code:

```
public class UniqueElements {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Set<Integer> uniqueKeys = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        //Use TreeSet to eliminate all duplicate integers in the array
        for (int runs = 0; runs <= 100; runs++) { //program loops 100 times
            for (int numbers = 1; numbers <= 140; numbers++) {
                //add 140 integers in array
                Random rand = new Random(System.nanoTime());
                uniqueKeys.add(rand.nextInt(numbers));
                //make the 140 integers random, including duplicates
            }
            System.out.print("Unique Elements: " + uniqueKeys + "\n");
            //print unique elements in array
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't quite do what you think it does.  It actually generates 14000 integers, from 140 different ranges (0 only, then 0 or 1, then 0, 1 or 2, and so on).

Comment: yeah its technically 14000 integers, but it's 100 sets of arrays with 140 elements (minus the duplicates) in each array. It was fine when I ran it.

Comment: `System.out.println(14000);`

Answer (score 4):

One way to count the number of comparison is to pass your own `Comparator<Integer>` instance to the constructor of `TreeSet` instead of using the parameterless constructor (which relies on the `compareTo` method of `Integer`).

This way you will implement the `compare` method yourself, and will be able to increment a count whenever it is called.

For example :

```
...

Set<Integer> uniqueKeys = new TreeSet<Integer>(new MyComparator());

...

public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Integer>
{
    private int count = 0;

    public int compare (Integer a, Integer b)
    {
        count++;
        System.out.println(count); // instead of printing the counter each time
                                   // this method is called, you can print it
                                   // once at the end of your program
        return Integer.compare(a,b);          
    }
}
```

As mentioned by David Wallace, you should probably fix your random number generation logic :

```
Random rand = new Random(); // use a single Random generator
int max = ...;
for (int numbers = 1; numbers <= 140; numbers++) {      
    uniqueKeys.add(rand.nextInt(max)); // use the same range for all 
                                       // the random generated numbers
}
```

Comment: ah, thank you! and i'll be sure to fix my random number generator